# KvmSerializabled object class members are null in server side

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have to pass custom object to WCF web-service. I had referred the [link](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html)  to pass customized object WCF web-serice from Android. But on the server side, class members are not assigned. For example I have assigned `Category.Name="test"` in the web-service client side, but on the server side the `Category` class member is null. Please guide me to solve this.

Note: I am using KSOAP2 for web-service consuming.